# How to model MOSFET as a switch on LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, switches

I am trying to use MOSFET as a switch on my circuit. I hope someone can help me model it!
[image]

Comment: You need Vgs > Vt by enough to fully enhance the FET.  If you want your output vout to be 25 at the SOURCE of the FET, then what does your gate voltage have to be?

Comment: For a high side switch you normally use a PMOS. Also, 25V is a tad too much...

Comment: You'll need a resistor in series with the gate drive; also need 1,000pF from gate to source, and 500pF from gate to drain.